# Multiple versions of the same reference vs2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I have MVC project with Npgsql nuget package installed version 3.2.5
Now I need to refernce another project to this MVC project that also uses Npgsql package but with newer version 4.1.3

When I use the project reference services in the MVC project I get an error in runtime that could not find Npgsql 4.1.3

Ofcourse its because MVC project knows Npgsql version 3.2.5

Is there anyway to reference the project and force it to use its own Npgsql packcge ?

What is the best way to solve those kind of isses?

Thank you

Comment: You may use [binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) for that

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if I use redirect binding that means that the MVC project will always use the newer version? because when I tried to upgrade Npgsql package MVC project crashed in runtime

Comment: You can specify which version to use or even provide a codebase. If MVC project will crash, maybe there is some breaking changes between 4.1.3 and 3.2.5 of Npgsql ?

Comment: another issue is that MVC project has submodule reference that also uses Npgsql version 3.2.5 so it's impossible to upgrade the submodule Npgsql package